# Lock screen timeout not working Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, lock-screen, timeout

I'm using kubuntu 16.04 and since two days ago lock screen timeout is not working any more. I have checked the log and don't see anything strange so is there any specific log that I should check in this case ? 2 Days before everything was working great and screen was getting locked after 5 minutes according to settings but now my screen gets turned off but there is no lock.